# Yii2/PHP/MySQL - decimals are truncated giving false results by multiplication

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, decimal

In MySQL I have an attribute `P10` which is a decimal(6,2). If I echo it in Yii2, I'm getting `20,45` - why the comma, why not point? It doesn't matter how I'm setting `decimalSeparator` in config. If I multiply the `20,45` with `2.1` I'm getting **42** instead of **42.945** so it seems `20,45` is truncated to `20` when using in calculations and I have no idea why. I have already spent a lot of time with searching and it drives me slowly crazy.

Interesting also, I'm echoing two attributes in Yii2 gridview and both are decimal(6,2) in MySQL, but still the one is echoed with a point as decimal separator and the other as a comma...?

Do I have to explicitly tell Yii2 that a decimal is a decimal, and format it extra as a decimal ??

Can you please point me to the right direction?

the code:

```
public function getMea5() {
    return $this->P10 * 2.1;
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the code which is causing the problem.

Comment: and include the regional settings for your computer.

Comment: @NigelRen code added. @JoSSte which setting is it? Locale? it is `de`

Comment: Comma vs decimal point -- check your "locale".

Answer (score 0):

> 20,45 is truncated to 20

Yes.  When a string (namely "20,45") is used in a numeric context (`*`), the string is parsed as far as it seems to be a number.  In this case, the `,` stops the number, thereby *ignoring* `,45`.  (Contrast: "*truncating*" which implies that the 45 would be included, then tossed.)

The way to get `20,45` instead of `20.45` is to have the "locale" set to, for example, "de" (German).

Here's an example taken from the [*manual*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format):

```
SELECT FORMAT(12332.2,2,'de_DE');
         -> '12.332,20'
```

Comment: But why it's becoming a string, when in MySQL it is stored as a decimal and has a point? And why does `decimalSeparator` not make any difference?

Comment: @user2511599 - A theory:  `20,45` was correctly stored as 20.45, based on Locale.  Then it was retrieved, again based on locale, it came back as `20,45`.  Now it is in the hands of yii2 to do the multiply (`return $this->P10 * 2.1;`).  Since the MySQL interface only returns strings, it is still `"20,45"` and that messes up in the multiply.  Print `P10`.  Concatinate `P10` with something and print that.  Research "local" in yii2.  (Sorry, I know nothing about yii/yii2.)